# What is the "DATA" keyword in T-SQL for?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with a database in T-SQL/SQL Server 2016 at the moment which has some stored procedures containing a keyword I'm not familiar with, namely the "DATA" suffix after a query:

`SELECT * FROM dbo.TableName DATA`

I'm struggling to find any documentation on what the purpose of this "DATA" keyword is. Could someone shed some light please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not some specific keyword. It is just a table alias. Note that if you changed your select to

```
SELECT DATA.* FROM dbo.TableName DATA
```

it will work, as the table now has the "DATA" alias. For the same reason, this:

```
SELECT dbo.TableName.* FROM dbo.TableName DATA
```

will throw an error.

Comment: I may have been thrown off by the unusual design of this sproc, the "DATA" suffix is used twice in separate inner queries but the "DATA" alias is never actually referenced within the query itself. It's also highlighting blue in my IDE due to "DATA" being a reserved keyword!

Comment: Logically the two joins are in a seperate nesting level, else there would be an error. Other than that, aliases are perfectly created without SEEMINGLY being used, although the only way to bypass them is when their fields have unique names among all the fields of all the joined tables.

Comment: @Wibbler, `DATA` is not currently a reserved keyword in SQL Server, although it is in the [future keyword list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql), That being said, a more descriptive name for aliases will avoid conflicts with keywords and also avoid the confusion it caused you here.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alias for the table name, usually it is used if we are inner joining the same table more than one time, or when we need to call the table with a shortcut name.
For example if the table has a key named ID, then:

```
   SELECT DATA.* FROM dbo.TableName DATA
where DATA.ID = "1"
```

is like

```
  SELECT dbo.TableName.* FROM dbo.TableName 
where TableName .ID = "1"
```

Comment: You're half right, DATA is being used as an alias but your query example has invalid syntax due to the alias being declared but not then used. It should be `SELECT DATA.* FROM dbo.TableName DATA`

Comment: @jarlh the original query doesn't parse in T-SQL, would you argue that is a semantic rather than syntax problem?

Comment: @Wibbler, doesn't parse? Strange. However, if that's the case it's indeed a syntax error.